# Python analyzing a user-selected range of data from a plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, analytics, user-input

I'm working on a project analyzing all closing values of the DJIA through earlier this year.  I have the entire dataset plotted with a best fit polynomial, etc. I know that matplotlib allows the user to select a rectangle on the plot.  Is there a way I could use this rectangle to have the program run further analysis on just that section?

I understand how I could do it with user-inputted dates, but how could I do it without the user input?

Here is a selection of the data that I have:

```
Date,DJIA
5/2/1885,31.435
5/4/1885,30.6614
5/5/1885,30.5087
5/6/1885,30.824
5/7/1885,30.5038
5/8/1885,30.9226
5/9/1885,31.1443
5/11/1885,30.7945
5/12/1885,30.6565
5/13/1885,30.6565
etc.
```

So just dates and values.

Comment: matplotlib examples: [short](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/ginput_demo.html?highlight=ginput) or  [long](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/ginput_manual_clabel.html)

Comment: Interesting, thanks.  This might just do it.